# Nginx Proxy + NodeJS WebSocket + >17KB messages. No traffic. Who is the culprit?

Tags: node.js, go, nginx, websocket, buffer

Impossible to increase buffer width to avoid dropping frames

**OR**

Unable to manage WS fragmentation correctly

---

### Summary

**My goal:**

A very simple thing: have websocket tunnel to transfer at least 2/3 MB of data per tunnel. I need to send directory structure, therefore the data can be very many

**The problem:**

Sending WebSocket messages over 17KB, from A to B, cause a "communication lost" or packet drop/loss; the connection/tunnel remains up with the inability to send new messages over the same tunnel, from A to B; conversely, from B to A continues to work.

I must restart the tunnel to get functionality back.

It could also be an idea, the management of the packet heap that restarts the tunnel when the threshold is reached, but it is clear that I need to send more than the threshold at one time.

**The "signal path":**

```
GoLang app(Client) ---> :443 NGINX Proxy(Debian) ---> :8050 NodeJS WS Server
```

**The tests:**

- Sending X messages/chunks of 1000 byte each | messages are received up to the 17th chunk, the following ones are not received (*see below*)

**The analyses:**

- **Wireshark** on Go app shows the flow of all packets
- **tcpdump**, on Debian machine, set to listen on `eth` (public), shows the flow of all packets
- **tcpdump**, on Debian machine, set to listen on `lo` interface (for rev proxy scanning), shows the flow of all packets
- **NodeJS/fastify-websocket** `ws.on('message', (msg)=>{console.log(msg)})` shows up to the 17th chunk

**Code & Config:**

GoLang app relevant part

```
    websocket.DefaultDialer = &websocket.Dialer{
        Proxy:            http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        HandshakeTimeout: 45 * time.Second,
        WriteBufferSize:  1000, //also tried with 2000, 5000, 10000, 11000
    }

    c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)

    wsConn = c


    bufferChunk := 1000

    bufferSample := ""

    for j := 7; j <= bufferChunk; j++ {
        bufferSample = bufferSample + "0"
    }

    i := 1

    for {

        sendingBytes := i * bufferChunk
        fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(sendingBytes) + " bytes sent")
        wsConn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(bufferSample))     

        i++
        time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
    }
```

NGINX conf:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8050;
}
server {
    server_name my.domain.com;
    
        large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        
        proxy_buffers 8 2m;
        proxy_buffer_size 10m;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 10m;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_redirect off;
        #proxy_buffering off; ### ON/OFF IT'S THE SAME 
        
        # enables WS support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade"; ### "upgrade" it's the same
    }
    
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = my.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    server_name my.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

NodeJS code:

```
//index.js

const config = require("./config.js");
const fastify = require('fastify')();
const WsController = require("./controller");

fastify.register(require('fastify-websocket'), {
  /*these options are the same as the native nodeJS WS*/
  options :{
    maxPayload: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
    maxReceivedFrameSize: 131072,
    maxReceivedMessageSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
    autoAcceptConnections: false
  }
});

fastify.ready(err => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log("Server started")



  fastify.websocketServer
    .on("connection", WsController)

})


//controller.js
module.exports = (ws, req) => {
    ws.on("message", (msg) => {
        log("msg received"); //it is shown as long as the tunnel does not "fill" up to 17KB
    })

})
```

Comment: What's in the nginx access and error log files?

Comment: have you considered trying to test without nginx in the middle?

Comment: @O.Jones nothing, just `***.***.***.*** - - [31/Oct/2020:22:46:49 +0100] "GET /terminals HTTP/1.1" 101 63 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"` on access log when I close Go app. Error log is clean

Comment: @DanielFarrell Well, I thought about it. But indeed, the real problem seems (and I say SEEMS) NodeJS, seen the results of the tcpdump on `lo` interface. The packets pass through NGINX correctly, as I see them after the NGINX node. I must test with Chrome WS client because, contextually to NodeJS, I fear that an incorrect fragmentation at the source could be at the root of the problem. I will try and let you know

Comment: @DanielFarrell Chrome WS client tested. It's always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLVED

Updating **fastify** and **fastify-websocket** the problem disappeared. What a shame!

*I came up with this solution by creating a new cloud instance and installing everything from scratch.*

Just `npm update`.

Thank you all for your support